# Как правильно  определить функцию  в onClick? Выдает ошибку Unhandled Error: Undefined variable

Tags: javascript

Как правильно  определить функцию  fun1:

html-файл:

```
<script src="fun.js"></script>
```

js-файл  fun.js:

```
function fun1(){alert('fun1');}

function fun(){
  str='<input type=button  onClick="fun1()" value="Press"> ';
  document.open();
  document.write(str);
  document.close();
}
onload = fun;
```

Выдает:

> Unhandled Error: Undefined variable:
> fun1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://plnkr.co/edit/PLFCjK5I3Eg3QlS3D3fe?p=preview

Всё работает так же, как у вас написано, возможно, fun1 не в глобальной области определена.

Вообще говоря, не надо использовать onclick в разметке, document.write и пропускать слово window при обращении к глобальному контексту.

**Обновление**

да конечно, сделайте css класс show, в css как-то так:

```
body { display:none; }
body.show { display:block; }
```

в js

```
window.document.body.classList.add('show')
```

или (для старых браузеров)

```
window.document.body.className="show";
```

Comment: Спасибо! Работает. Предполагалось использовать только js и  чтобы страница отображалась только при включенном в браузере js. 
Можно ли реализовать это по-другому?

Comment: Обновил ответ

Answer (score 0):

В частности, в приведенном ТС примере ошибка в вызове функции на строчке `onload = fun;`, а нужно `onload = fun();`.

Здесь приведено полное решение: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/e1BU3exfbxp7WXO5umr2?p=preview

P.S. А лучше вообще делать, как указал [[@StixoTvorec](/users/25218/stixotvorec)](/users/25218/stixotvorec).

Comment: Верно (хоть и кривовато смотрится)

     onload = fun; 

Для понимания смотрим пример:

    var runIt;
    setTimeout(function() { //событие таймера через 1000мс
        runIt();
    },1000);
    
    
    
    function hello() {
       console.log("Hello world");
    }
    
    runIt=hello;

У ТС - событие окна `(load);`.

Answer (score 0):

По хорошему, лучше не использовать onClick.

В будущем посмотрите в сторону jQuery - отличная штука. :-)

А теперь о Вашем коде:

html-файл:

```
<script src="fun.js"></script>
```

Это еще можно простить, но вот...

js-файл fun.js

```
function fun1(){ alert('fun1'); }
function fun(){ str='<input type=button onClick="fun1()" value="Press"> ';
document.open(); document.write(str); document.close(); }
onload = fun;
```

Это, простите, что такое?

Я не пытаюсь Вас в чем-то упрекать, но это выглядит плохо.

По делу: у Вас лишние скобки в вызове, к тому же функцию Вы должны определять там, где будете производить вызов, т.е. на **открываемой** странице, а не на той, *которая* открывает.

Т.е. Вашим кодом:

```
function fun(){ str='<script>function fun1(){ alert('fun1'); }</script><input type=button onClick="fun1" value="Press"> ';
document.open(); document.write(str); document.close(); }
onload = fun();
```

Comment: См. коммент ниже.

Comment: Спасибо и за ваш совет, [@StixoTvorec](http://hashcode.ru/users/25218/stixotvorec).